# How do i access attributes in has_many :through relationship?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-3.1, has-many-through

How do i access store name here?@deal instance can access perfectly item name,but when i try to access store name it gives me

```
no method error 'stores'
```

How do i get store instance to access store name?Here is the code.Thank you in advance

controller

```
def show
   unless session[:city_id].nil? || session[:city_id].blank?
   @city = City.find(session[:city_id])
   @deal=@city.deals
   @store=@deal.stores
end
```

view/show

```
<% @deal.each do |deal| %>
<%=deal.item_name %>
<%end%>

<%=@store.store_name %>
```

models

```
class Store < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :deals ,:through =>:store_deals
    has_many :store_deals
end

class Deal < ActiveRecord::Base
    has_many :stores ,:through =>:store_deals
    has_many :store_deals
end

class StoreDeal < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :store
    belongs_to :deal
end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

@deal is most likely an array of deals. @city.deals implies you could have multiple deals per city. This wil cause a problem when you try to do

```
@deal=@city.deals
@store=@deal.stores
```

try something like:

```
@deals = @city.deals
@stores = @deals.collect(&:stores)
```

Comment: I just tried gave me....You have a nil object when you didn't expect it!
You might have expected an instance of Array.
The error occurred while evaluating nil.collect

Comment: the naming might be confusing here, there was a change from {at}deal to {at}deals, make sure you've changed all of your calls to {at}deal if you changed the variable in the controller (the @ symbol in comments is similar to facebook, so that's why i have {at}.)

Comment: Maybe i should ask what does .collect(&:stores) return?

Comment: you are iterating through the deals array and calling stores on each Deal object. The results get stores in @stores. now i think about it, you probably want to put a .uniq on it too so you don't get potential duplicates.